# how to center javascript innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html

ok first off hi i am totally new to this just started today and i was working on a script and need to add some inner html and was wondering do i need to center every line or center start than the end? and am i even doing it right ? and if you think i could do it a better way please let me know can not be jquery.

example A

```js
    var settingsHtml = '';
    settingsHtml += "<center><h3 style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\">settings</h3><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<button>TEXT HERE</button>&nbsp;";
    settingsHtml += "<button>TEXT HERE</button><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<br><hr style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\"><br>";
    settingsHtml += "text here<br>";
    settingsHtml += "text here<br>";
    settingsHtml += "text here<br>";
    settingsHtml += "<br><hr style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\"><br>";
    settingsHtml += "More Coming Soon!</center><br>";

    document.getElementsByClassName("hud-settings-grid")[0].innerHTML = settingsHtml;
```

```html
<div class="hud-settings-grid"> </div>
```

or example B

```js
var settingsHtml = '';
    settingsHtml += "<center><h3 style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\">settings</h3></center><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<center><button>TEXT HERE</button>&nbsp;";
    settingsHtml += "<button>TEXT HERE</button></center><br><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<center><hr style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\"></center><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<center>text here</center><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<center>text here</center><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<center>text here</center><br><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<center><hr style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\"></center><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<center>More Coming Soon!</center><br>";

    document.getElementsByClassName("hud-settings-grid")[0].innerHTML = settingsHtml;
```

```html
<div class="hud-settings-grid"> </div>
```

Comment: `<center>` is obsolete: http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/the-x-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead/the-center-element-is-obsolete-use-css-instead/

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping everything with `<center> .... </center>`

Should be enough.

BUT, `center` is an [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) HTML tag.
You should use:

`<div style="text-align:center"> .... </div>`

Comment: Nice! that will help me alot.

Answer (score 1):

A better method would be to change the elements style by setting the `text-align` css property of the whole `<div>` to `'center'`, since the [`<centre>` tag is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

```js
var settingsHtml = '';
    settingsHtml += "<h3 style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\">settings</h3><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<button>TEXT HERE</button>&nbsp;";
    settingsHtml += "<button>TEXT HERE</button><br>";
    settingsHtml += "<br><hr style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\"><br>";
    settingsHtml += "text here<br>";
    settingsHtml += "text here<br>";
    settingsHtml += "text here<br>";
    settingsHtml += "<br><hr style=\"color: rgba(255, 255, 255);\"><br>";
    settingsHtml += "More Coming Soon!<br>";

    let div = document.getElementsByClassName("hud-settings-grid")[0]
    div.innerHTML = settingsHtml;
    div.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

```html
<div class="hud-settings-grid"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use deafult center tag of html5 in your div so you will get your solution.

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is =  not need put  to every element.
Just put your code inner html tag 
or use css with your div element. 
For example your

css code =>

```
.hud-settings-grid{
   align-text: center;
    or your css code .....
}
```